# Unable to detect the app label for model

Tags: python, django

This question has morphed a little.  The original question was based on faulty data.

I have gotten a little further in my error tracking...  It seems that the core django code is working fine (it can read and write to the database correctly.  The problem is that I have another python app that is using the same django code to read the database.  It is running as root and is not working...

In order for the app to be able to read the django setup, I have this in the beginning of the file:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("/home/pi/garageMonitor/django/garageMonitor"))
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'garageMonitor.settings'
import models
```

Here is the error I am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../scripts/startPio.py", line 18, in <module>
    from webWatcher import WebWatcher
  File "/home/pi/garageMonitor/django/lib/webWatcher.py", line 14, in <module>
    import models
  File "/home/pi/garageMonitor/django/garageMonitor/models.py", line 11, in <module>
    class DoorClosing(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 131, in __new__
    'app.' % (new_class.__name__, model_module.__name__)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Unable to detect the app label for model "DoorClosing." Ensure that its module, "models", is located inside an installed app.
```

I do have a DoorClosing model in models.py (and it happens to be the first model in the file):

```
class DoorClosing(models.Model):
  door_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
  start = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  stop = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

  def __str__(self):
    return "DoorClosing" \
      + ",Start:" + str(self.start)\
      + ",Stop:" + str(self.stop) \
      + "\n"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no such flag as `--install`, and it would not change the database.

Comment: Something is updating the database. The column is inserted correctly

Comment: Actually there is an install argument in (my) manage.py:#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
import argparse

if __name__ == "__main__":
  os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "garageMonitor.settings")
  from garageMonitor.models import config
  from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='')
  parser.add_argument('--install', action='store_true', required=False)
  args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()

  if args.install:
    config()
  else:
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

Comment: It would be great to provide the Django version. I can't find it even in your voluminous edits (which is not great by itself - it's better to create new specific questions).

Answer (score 0):

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

This syncs all of your model changes with your database.

You could specify this further by following that up with the specific app name, if you so choose. But as it is, it will search every app in your `settings.py` and update the database accordingly.

Edit: Never mind, I think your problem may exist in the column itself. :s

Comment: I am doing this also.  It does update the database correctly, but when I try to use the new column in the model, I get an error.

Comment: I too made an edit ;-) I showed the error message as well as the calling code in my question.

Answer (score 0):

There are mainly three steps to create the database with your models defined in models.py:

```
python manage.py makemigrations <app_name>
python manage.py sqlmigrate <app_name> 0001
python manage.py migrate
```

After that any changes happen in the model such as adding a column and so on, you just need to run `python manage.py syncdb` and then you may need to run `python manage.py migrate` again.

Comment: The problem is not that the database is not being updated, the problem is that the model does not recognize the column after the database is updated.

Comment: You suggest that the error is in the model. Can you please be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Django 1.7 [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.7/#app-registry-consistency) state:

It is no longer possible to have multiple installed applications with the same label. In previous versions of Django, this didn’t always work correctly, but didn’t crash outright either.

If you have two apps with the same label, you should create an AppConfig for one of them and override its label there. You should then adjust your code wherever it references this application or its models with the old label.

It isn’t possible to **import the same model twice** through different paths any more. As of Django 1.6, this may happen only if you’re manually **putting a directory and a subdirectory on PYTHONPATH**. Refer to the section on the new project layout in the 1.4 release notes for migration instructions.

You should make sure that:

- All models are defined in applications that are listed in INSTALLED_APPS or have an explicit app_label.
- Models aren’t imported as a side-effect of loading their application. Specifically, you shouldn’t import models in the root module of an application nor in the module that define its configuration class.

(end of copy-paste, markup mine). In my case all was fixed by adjusting the PYTHONPATH.